# Binding window title to child property

Tags: wpf, binding, window

I've got a window with my custom textbox-like control on it

```
<Window.Title>
    <Binding ElementName="codeBox" Path="Filename" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</Window.Title>
...
<custom:CodeArea Name="codeBox">
</custom:CodeArea>
```

here what I have inside my CodeArea back code (CodeArea.xaml.cs)

```
private string _filename = "NoName";
public string Filename
{
    get { return _filename; }
    set { _filename = value; }
}
```

When application starts, it has 'NoName' title. If I open any file, Filename setter *is* called, but title doesn't change. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to notify WPF the property has changed, you can either implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your class or make FileName a DependencyProperty